# How to get md-button caption

Tags: angular-material

I make a short app, using Angular Material. I have an array of md-buttons, each with different caption.  How to get what buttons was clicked or how do I get the caption of the button when is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/mOyaeO?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout="column" layout-align="start start">
    <md-button ng-repeat="button in ctrl.buttons"
               class="md-raised md-primary"
               ng-click="ctrl.click($index)">{{button}}</md-button>
    Button caption: {{ctrl.selectedButton}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.buttons = ["Car", "Train", "Plane", "Rocket"];

  this.click = function (index) {
    this.selectedButton = this.buttons[index];
  }
});
```